# Identify missing Dimension Value in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have student name, subject and marks in three columns. My use case is to identify the subject in which selected student has not enrolled. I can do it very easily using SQL but requirement is to identify it in Tableau. I have tried LOD's and Traditional Filters but it's of no help.

```
**Sample Data**- 
Name    Subject Marks
Rob A   90
Rob B   95
Rob C   98
Ted B   86
Ted D   70


**Desired Output**-
Name    Subject
Rob D
Ted A
Ted C
```

Comment: Hi there, please look at this [guide how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If graphical solutions are also an option, you can print the Subjects on e.g. the X axis, and the Student Names on the Y axis. Then, set the marks type to e.g. text and display the Number of Records in each cell. This way, you should get a matrix of all Subject vs. all Students, with 0 or 1 in each cell (intersection).

Comment: Thank You Jan. Unfortunately, in this case, the important information is not readily available in the matrix view and user needs to read the matrix carefully for determining the missing values.

Comment: I solved this issue using custom SQL's by legacy connection.